# How can you convert "tinyint" of t-sql to integer in c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a `tinyint` column in the database and I wish to convert it to `Int32` for an `SqlDataReader`.

How do i go about it?

**Edit #1**

I recently had to do this.

```
int a = dataReader.GetByte(dr.GetOrdinal("ColumnName"));
```

**#In Addition to Answer**

SQL Server Data Type Mappings

```
bigint           - GetInt64  
binary           - GetBytes  
int              - GetInt32  
money            - GetDecimal  
rowversion       - GetBytes  
smallint         - GetInt16  
tinyint          - GetByte  
uniqueidentifier - GetGuid   
...
```

For more info visit - [SQL Server Data Type Mappings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

What does it normally come back as - byte? If so, just do an unbox and then a convert:

```
(int)(byte) reader["column"];
```

or just let the conversion happen naturally:

```
int x = (byte) reader["column"];
```

or do the same with the strongly typed methods:

```
int x = reader.GetByte(column);
```

Adjust this to `sbyte` or `short` or whatever if I'm wrong about it mapping to `byte`. You could do the conversion at the SQL Server side, but I'd personally do it at the client side instead, and keep the SQL simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Use "SByte" works every-time For handling the Tiny Int problem

Comment: `sbyte`  –128 to 127   `tinyint`  0 to 255 - you might reconsider this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
int RetValue;
RetValue = (int)(byte)dt.Rows[A][B]  // A = RowNo , B = 'tinyint' Column Name.
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a tinyint from a sql table i do the following:

```
retorno = Convert.ToInt32(dr.GetByte(dr.GetOrdinal("StepStatus")));
```

Where retorno is a int variable.

I hope this help you.