# Invalid cast reading data from table

Tags: c#, asp.net, casting

My Users table has a field called `Admin` which is `tinyint(1)`. 1 for admin, 0 for normal user.

I want to set a session variable when users log in that is either true or false depending on if they're admin or not.

```
if ((int)Reader["Admin"] == 0)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session["Admin"] = false;
}
else
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session["Admin"] = true;
}
```

`Reader` is a `SqlDataReader`. The code produces the following error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

How can I properly cast `Reader["Admin"]` to an int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because tinyint gets turned into a System.Byte which can't be explicitly cast to an System.Int32

You will have to use [Convert.ToInt32(Byte)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7hk2thbx.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`tinyint` converts to `Byte` in C#. Change the cast/condtional to

```
 (Byte)Reader["Admin"] == 0
```

Comment: isn't the right hand side is a int? and you are comparing a byte to an int?

Comment: @krshekhar `Byte.minValue = 0` the integers from 0-255 are all valid `Byte` values.

Comment: @krshekhar - It is relying on an Implicit cast. The code is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below links

[How can you convert "tinyint" of t-sql to integer in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922094/how-can-you-convert-tinyint-of-t-sql-to-integer-in-c)

[MSDN Reference about CLR Type conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx)